Formatted TextLabel doesn't show the correct values
I need help with a gas gauge for a car in Roblox.
Setup:
DriveSeat (VehicleSeat) and GasValue (NumberValue) are in the same car model.
I have a GasGUI with a TextLabel that displays the gas percentage.
I used a LocalScript in the TextLabel.
The issue is that the script only shows "Gas: --%" even when I enter the car, and I want it to show how much gas is in the car.
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local gasLabel = script.Parent
gasLabel.Text = "Gas: --%"

local function onDriveSeatChanged(driveSeat)
    if driveSeat.Occupant and driveSeat.Occupant.Parent == player.Character then
        local car = driveSeat.Parent
        local gasValue = car:FindFirstChild("GasValue")

        if gasValue then
            gasLabel.Text = "Gas: " .. math.floor(gasValue.Value) .. "%"
            gasValue:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect(function()
                gasLabel.Text = "Gas: " .. math.floor(gasValue.Value) .. "%"
            end)
        else
            gasLabel.Text = "Gas: N/A"
        end
    else
        gasLabel.Text = "Gas: --%" 
    end
end

I'm not sure what isn't working.

Do you ever call the onDriveSeatChanged function? Is it connected to a Seat anywhere?

Also what are your errors?

In the function you don't check if the driveSeat parameter is a seat object. Nestle the rest of your code with if if driveseat:IsA("Seat") then. Also you don't connect the function in your code. Connect the function via this seat.Sat:Connect(OnDriveSeatChanged). Make sure your code is called correctly and that unknown parameters are not used as objects.
